# models not showing on django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm just starting my first project using Django 1.11. I followed the same steps I've used on multiple Django 1.10 projects, but for some reason my models are not showing up on my localhost/admin site.

My INSTALLED_APPS from settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
]
```

My admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from home.models import Home

# begin Admin Class Definitions
class HomeAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ('Title', {'fields': ['title']}),
        ('Publication Date', {'fields': ['pub_date']}),
        ('Home Page Text', {'fields': ['header', 'sub_header', 
         'link_text']}),
    ]
    list_display = ('title', 'pub_date')
    list_filter = ['pub_date']

admin.site.register(Home, HomeAdmin)
```

My [main_app]/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('home.urls'))
]
```

But when I go to `localhost:8000/admin` the only things present are Groups and Users as if I hadn't registered any models at all.

I have run makemigrations and migrate, and I have tried putting admin.py within the app directory instead of the project directory. It's currently in the [project_name]/[project_name] directory (the one with settings.py, urls.py, and wsgi.py files).

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about removing the `admin.autodiscover()` ??

Comment: no change, unfortunately

Comment: What is 'home.apps.HomeConfig'? If your app is called `home`, installed apps should list `'home'`. Also put it on top of the list, not the bottom.

Comment: When several applications provide different versions of the same resource (template, static file, management command, translation), the application listed first in INSTALLED_APPS has precedence. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Are the Django's admin built-in models, like `user`, `group` visible?

Comment: Django's built-in apps are visible, it's only mine that aren't. I did try just naming it 'home' with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use the Django admin always import in this form:

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

And inherint in the class:

```
class HomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
```

So your admin.py file would looke like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from home.models import Home

# begin Admin Class Definitions
class HomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ('Title', {'fields': ['title']}),
        ('Publication Date', {'fields': ['pub_date']}),
        ('Home Page Text', {'fields': ['header', 'sub_header', 
         'link_text']}),
    ]
    list_display = ('title', 'pub_date')
    list_filter = ['pub_date']

admin.site.register(Home, HomeAdmin)
```

Comment: that is exactly what my admin.py looked like in the original question.

Comment: Well in your class you have:

class HomeAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):

and don't know where models.ModelAdmin came from, 
try using: admin.ModelAdmin

Comment: Oh my god you're right. That right there was the problem.

Sorry for being snarky.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to register your models to the admin. I normally do it like this if it's a simple model.

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import *

    # Register your models here.
    @admin.register(Model)
    class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): pass
```

Comment: I tried registering it with the decorator and with `admin.site.register(Model, ModelAdmin)` and neither way worked.

Answer (score 2):

I gave up trying to diagnose my problem, and nuked the project and started over. It works fine now. I'm honestly not sure what the problem was. If anyone is curious, here are my new files:

from settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

from urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

from admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import HomePageText

admin.site.register(HomePageText)
```

I honestly don't understand why it wasn't working before. If anyone with more insight can spot some difference that I can't please let me know.

Comment: I ran into this as well and could not get it working even with the most simple app. Worked after nuking everything. Considering this is 2 years later, it can't be a bug in Django unless it's a regression bug.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid and obvious suggestion, but Django admin changes don't always appear to be picked up immediately. If everything appears to be configured correctly (models and admins registered, apps installed etc), try a server restart - after all the suggestions above, ultimately, this did it for me.